# Python Glade GTK - How to prepare many windows application

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

A simple application with a few screens. The user can navigate with BACK-NEXT buttons. How do you prepare such an application in Python and GTK Glade?

I mean how do you hide the previous components? What is the most practical way? I couldn't find any tutorial on the net. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for [GtkAssistant](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/GtkAssistant.html).

I tried playing around with it and found that Glade makes it really hard to use, but the things you should be looking at are:

- *Back* and *Forward* to navigate through the pages
- *Number of Pages* in the GtkAssistant properties
- *Page Type* and *Position* in the children properties

If things look weird, try changing pages and going back.